# Build array from mysql with inserted value for fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, fputcsv

I am trying to build an array from db but need to insert a calculated value: `$group`,  into each row of output. When I plug it into `fputcsv`, the resulting file says:

```
Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array.  
null given in /update-csv.php on line 67
```

My related code reads as follows:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $updateArray[][] = array(  
        array( $row['firstLast'], $row['firstName'], ($row['lastName'], $group,$row['email'])); 
    fputcsv($output, $updateArray);
```

NOTE: This is line 67

I believe my error is in building the array but can't figure out where it's wrong.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think those additional brackets in your array should be there

Comment: You're creating a 3-dimensional array. `fputcsv` expects the 2nd argument to be a 1-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overkill. Unless you're trying to save each array for later in the script, all you need is this:

```
$updateArray = array( $row['firstLast'], $row['firstName'], $row['lastName'], $group, $row['email'] );
```

Comment: I had that originally and got: **syntax error, unexpected ',' in...** referring to that line of code. If I add quotes around `$group`, i.e., `"$group"`, the script completes and I get the same warning message as originally stated.

Comment: Yep, had a stray `(` in there. Answer edited. If you take that out, it should work.

Comment: That did it - Thanks!